Get pyspark corrupt records reason
I'm using spark to read a json file that has some corrupt records. So I'm using option mode PERMISSIVE and option columnNameOfCorruptRecord to get all corrupt records. Everything is working fine, however I also need to get the reason for each row why that record is corrupted.
For example:
Json file:
[{"name":"Jorge", "age": 25, "city": "Manhattan"},
{"name":"Natasha", "age": 34, "city": True},
{"name":"Kelly", "age": 42.5, "city": "New York"}]

Schema:
schema = StructType([
  StructField("name", StringType(), True),
  StructField("age", IntegerType(), True),
  StructField("city", StringType(), True)
])

For row 2, the corrupt record is column "city". For row 3, the corrupt record is column "age". Spark put all information together on the column defined in columnNameOfCorruptRecord. Is there any way to get also the reason of each row why that record is corrupted?In my real case, I have a schema with more than 100 fields, so I need to identify for each corrupt record why that row is corrupted.

You could leverage the corrupted data validation using marshmallow a python external library. You might have to install this first pip install marshmallow.

Imports

from marshmallow import Schema, fields, ValidationError
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, regexp_replace, udf
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, StructType, StructField, StringType


Lets start with Marshmallow Schema definition (used against corrupted record)

class IntConstraint(fields.Field):
    def _deserialize(self, value, attr, data, **kwargs):
        if isinstance(value, int):
            return value
        else:
            raise ValidationError("Field should be int")

class Person(Schema):        
    name = fields.Str(required=True)
    age  = IntConstraint(required=True)
    city = fields.Str(required=True)

Note: We have defined our own IntConstraint as marshmalow by default accepts float as int.

Prepare Spark DataFrame

schema = StructType([
  StructField("name", StringType(), True),
  StructField("age", IntegerType(), True),
  StructField("city", StringType(), True),
  StructField("_corrupt_record", StringType(), True)
])

df = spark.read.format("json") \
    .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE") \
    .option("path", "<your_file_path") \
    .schema(schema) \
    .load()

df = df \
    .withColumn("_corrupt_record", regexp_replace(col("_corrupt_record"), "True", "true")) \
    .withColumn("_corrupt_record", regexp_replace(col("_corrupt_record"), "False", "false"))


Validate corrupted Data

@udf
def validate_user(json_string):
    try:
        if json_string is not None:
            Person().loads(json_string)
        return None
    except ValidationError as error:
        return error.messages


validated_df = df.withColumn("validation_error", validate_user(col("_corrupt_record")))

validated_df.show(truncate = False)

Output:
+-----+----+---------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+
|name |age |city     |_corrupt_record                                  |validation_error            |
+-----+----+---------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+
|Jorge|25  |Manhattan|null                                             |null                        |
|null |null|null     |{"name":"Natasha", "age": 34, "city": true}      |{city=[Not a valid string]}|
|Kelly|null|New York |{"name":"Kelly", "age": 42.5, "city": "New York"}|{age=[Field should be int]} |
+-----+----+---------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+

