Optimize - Read all errors and then raise exception in pyspark
I want to read a CSV file and then get all the erroneous records and their errors. If there are errors, I need to raise an exception; otherwise, I will append the results to a table.
I have written some code for that
df = (
    spark
    .read
    .option("header", True)
    .option("badRecordsPath", "/bad_records/<current_date>")
    .schema(spark.table("bronze_table").schema)
    .csv("source_file.csv")
)

df.count()

if <current_date> in dbutils.fs.ls("/bad_records/")[-1].name:
    raise Exception("Erroneous records present")
else:
    db.write.insertInto("bronze_table")

The problem with the above approach is that I need to call an action like df.count() to read the files and form the bad record path. Then, if there are no erroneous records, another action (df.write.insertInto) is called, which will run the entire DAG again, starting from reading the file.
I want to avoid reading the file again. I cannot use the following options

cache - because it can give memory issues
columnNameOfCorruptedRecord - because it doesn't give the error which occurred

I can use persist with MEMORY_AND_DISK to avoid memory issues. Is there anything better than that? Something that I am not aware of. I am on a unity-catalog enabled Databricks platform (14.3 LTS)

persist and cache are the same thing

@samkart you can see the following link for difference between persist and cache.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78354606/get-pyspark-corrupt-records-reason
https://medium.com/@sasidharan-r/how-to-handle-corrupt-or-bad-record-in-apache-spark-custom-logic-pyspark-aws-430ddec9bb41
